# How does one use :wildcards in parent routes?

Tags: express

I'm building an express app in express 4.0 (rc3), since I'm starting from scratch and in development for a while, but if there's a way to do this in 3.0, that'd be welcome too.

What I want is a set of comment REST routes that I can attach to other routes in my API. So:

/posts/:postID/comments/:commentID
/profiles/:profileID/comments/:commentID

The way I *was* doing it was to encapsulate the comment routes into a module, including a buildRoutes(router) function in the module.

Then I can do `app.use('/api/comments', commentController.buildRoutes(express.Router()))` in my main server definition, and then in my profile module's `buildRoutes(router)`, I can do

```
buildRoutes = function(profileRouter)
.... build the basic CRUD routes ...
profileRouter.get('/:profileID', show)
profileRouter.use('/:profileID', commentController.buildRoutes(express.Router()))
```

It seems like only the .VERB methods actually replace :wildcards in the route, and not the .use one. I could always muddle through with a piece of custom middleware that goes on a /api/profiles/* and maps the appropriate URL parameters into req.fields, but I want to make sure that this is actually required.

Answer (score 0):

So this wasn't particularly easy to do the way I originally intended. However, I just avoided the entire problem by reframing my buildRoutes method to accept a baseURL and a router argument. Instead of modularizing it completely, now I say, `profileController.buildRoutes('/api/profiles/', router)` which in turn calls `commentController.buildRoutes('/api/profiles/:profileID/comments', router)`, and so on.

It's not terribly satisfying (I would rather encapsulate path/routing information and hide that from the controller) but it works.